# How to generate multiple csv files from dataSet which is having multiple tables

Tags: c#, csv, io, dataset, filestream

I want to generate multiple different different .csv files from Dataset (which hold many tables inside)

I tried like following but do not know code to generate different csv.

```
 public string GenerateCSVfiles(List<DataSet> dataSets)
        {
               //create csv file
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    result.Append(row[i].ToString());
                    result.Append(i == dataTable.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ",");
                }
            }

            return result.ToString();

            }

            //return Files in .zip;
        }
```

Comment: what's do you wanna to return in the GenerateCSVfiles and do you wanna to generate each file separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code: The csv filenames are generated using datatable name:

```
public void GenerateCSVfiles(DataSet dataSets)
{
    //create csv file
    StreamWriter sw = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSets.Tables)
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(string.Format(@"C:\Temp\{0}.csv", dataTable.TableName));

        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Clear();

            for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                sb.Append(dataTable.Rows[i][j]);
                if (j != (dataTable.Columns.Count - 1)) sb.Append(",");
            }
            sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but this will add an extra comma in the end. I would say add `if(j == (dataTable.Columns.Count - 1)) sb.Append(",");`